# Is there a simple replacement for `from win32api import keybd_event, GetAsyncKeyState` for linux users?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard-events

I want to use a game mapping script written for Windows [here](https://github.com/sulli42/THE_LONG_DARK/blob/master/TLD_mapping_tool.ipynb) that uses this very simple line:

`from win32api import keybd_event, GetAsyncKeyState`

I wonder if there is a similar easy line I could use in Linux.

In other words, I just need a way to signal to the running script when to start reading coordinates and when to stop...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to intercept HID Keyboard events (and then block them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668872/need-to-intercept-hid-keyboard-events-and-then-block-them)

Comment: Not really. I took a look. But I'm not an expert on C or Linux. I know my away around python and was just trying to use a script originally thought for Windows.