# Gettin key release events in ncurses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

Is it possible to detect when keys are released in ncurses?

I managed to get the functionality I want by following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20946151/3451896) answer. However, it requires `sudo` to work properly, which is not ideal for my use case.

Comment: This is not possible. `curses` works with terminal emulators, they don't provide keypress and release information.

Comment: Ncurses does not know anything about keys. It receives *characters* from the terminal or terminal emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving key press and key release events in Linux terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409216/receiving-key-press-and-key-release-events-in-linux-terminal-applications)