How can I detect if multiple keyboard keys are being pressed at the same time in C++, in Linux, from the terminal?
I have some code which currently checks if the character "b" is being pressed:
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

char getKeyPress() {
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    char ch;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return ch;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Press 'b' to see if it's detected. Press 'q' to quit." << endl;

    while (true) {
        char key = getKeyPress();

        if (key == 'b') {
            cout << "'b' is currently pressed." << endl;
        }

        if (key == 'q') {
            cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

However in my real code base, I need to check for multiple characters being pressed. How could I extend this code to check if "b" or "n" are being pressed, and if both "b" and "n" are being pressed at the same time?

Narrow it down: do you just mean terminal input like shown or the wide world of arbitrary evdev input devices?

Just terminal input, but if there is a better alternative I would like to know as well

I don't know if curses support it, but I would rather use it anyway than doing all the terminal handling myself.

What do you mean by "at the same time"?  A key going down sends an event.  A key being released sends an event.  Do you mean that the "key pressed" event occurs simultaneously with the others, or do you mean that "key pressed" for one key happens before "key released" for the other key?

@WilliamPursell I have a program where I need to know if specific keyboard buttons is currently being pressed, on windows I can do this with just looping over the characters I want to check and call GetAsyncKeyState(static_cast<int>(ch)) & 0x8000;. I want to make an equivalent function to do that on Linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375390/gettin-key-release-events-in-ncurses

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409216/receiving-key-press-and-key-release-events-in-linux-terminal-applications

The answer will probably depend on the terminal handler -- the solution with X will be different than that with iOS or when running under WSL, for example, and it's quite possible that some terminal handlers do not provide a means of accessing the individual events (key down and key up). Also, it's probable that whatever the method, it won't return ASCII values like 'b', but rather the key code, which depends on the position of the key on the keyboard. Depending on the keyboard driver I have installed, for example, the same key may be a w or a z.

Terminals deal with characters, not keys.
